# Row with the highest ID

Tags: sql

You have three fields ID, Date and Total. Your table contains multiple rows for the same day which is valid data however for reporting purpose you need to show only one row per day. The row with the highest ID per day should be returned the rest should be hidden from users (not returned).
To better picture the question below is sample data and sample output:

```
ID, Date, Total
1, 2011-12-22, 50
2, 2011-12-22, 150
```

The correct result is:

```
2, 2012-12-22, 150
```

The correct output is single row for 2011-12-22 date and this row was chosen because it has the highest ID (2>1)

Comment: What SQL? (e.g MySQL, SQL Server etc.)

Comment: I assume that there are further rows for *other* days (your example is rather *too* trivial, I feel, if that's the case). Also, what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1` or `SELECT MAX(ID) FROM TABLE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assuming* that you have a database that supports window functions, and that the `date` column is indeed just `date` (and not `datetime`), then something like:

```
SELECT
    * --TODO - Pick columns
FROM
    (
       SELECT ID,[Date],Total,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Date] ORDER BY ID desc) rn
       FROM [Table]
    ) t
WHERE
   rn = 1
```

Should produce one row per day - and the selected row for any given day is that with the highest `ID` value.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE ID IN ( SELECT MAX(ID)
              FROM table
              GROUP BY Date )
```

Comment: wouldn't that query the database 2 times? Guess that would take longer than giving a single query instruction though it should work that way.

Comment: @Stefan I'm assuming there more rows in the database than the 2 sample ones the OP provided. I am also assuming the table contains data for many days and the query is supposed to return one row for every day.

Answer (score 1):

This will work.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tableName a
            INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT `DATE`, MAX(ID) maxID
                FROM tableName
                GROUP BY `DATE`
            ) b ON a.id = b.MaxID AND
                a.`date` = b.`date`
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3aaa9/5)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select MAX(ID),Data,Total from foo
```

for MySQL

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your solution won't work in most SQL implementations (given that `Data` and `Total` aren't included in either an aggregate or a `GROUP BY` clause). Unfortunately, despite a few requests, the OP never clarified what database system they were using. I believe your answer *may* work on MySQL - so would be worth adding that to your answer as an explicit assumption. Also, format code by hitting the `{}` button. Finally, it's part of the SO setup that, unfortunately, downvoters don't *have* to give a reason.

Comment: I am not aware that there is no obligation to give a reason - though I think it's always respectful (and helpful) to give a short reason why to downvote an answer. This is a place to help and discuss - if you have time to downvote, take your time to explain what you don't like.

Answer (score 0):

Probably

```
SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way is

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM YourTable ORDER BY ID DESC
```

And, I think this is the most simple way!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_SUM S WHERE S.ID = 
( 
SELECT MAX(ID) FROM TABLE_SUM
WHERE CDATE = GG.CDATE
GROUP BY CDATE 
)
```